# Plotting Streamlines of Karman vortex in Python/FORTRAN

Tags: python, fortran

I'm computing Incompressible Navier-Stokes 2D Flow around a [rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TjKx.jpg).

Using the example code handed in the class in FORTRAN 77, I've managed to solve and get the .data file output, but I'm having trouble plotting it. My main program goes like:

```
  open(unit=60,file='flow.data',form='unformatted')
  open(unit=70,file='hist.data',form='formatted') 
  call setflw
  call setgrd
  call slvflw
  close(unit=60)
  close(unit=70)
  stop
  end
```

and I have a subroutine that outputs the flow data in a .dat file like:

```
  write(60) re,cfl,dt,nlast,time
  write(60) mx,i1,i2,my,j1,j2
  write(60)((x(i,j),y(i,j),i=1,mx),j=1,my)
  write(60)((u(i,j),v(i,j),p(i,j),i=1,mx),j=1,my)
```

so I'm sure I have the data for it in the [flow.data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jnTJ-WgoUfwWGIgcEM3fOjYRvOeCGYks/view?usp=sharing) file. But (I think) its in binary, and with me still a beginner, I have no idea how to plot them. I would like to know the way to plot streamlines/pressure fields individually in either FORTRAN 77 or Python or gnuplot (if any is possible)

This is the [.for file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gMtdBriOG3EslytRo-EQzg8pmz7MaNJO/view?usp=sharing) and the [.exe file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ySnVrnfzcpLXwdTxbMPLAdC_f0FTGX_R/view?usp=sharing)  I've made based on the lecture slides

Comment: Welcome, please read [ask]. This is a programming site to help you with your code. Please do not make your questions too broad. Ask about how to read the data in one question and about the plotting in another question. But please try to ask about programming with some method already in mind. Or ask just about the method.

Comment: Note that *Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.* is a reason to close a question, do not ask for something too broad.